# PHP Session data gets lost after page refresh

Tags: php, html, session, refresh, cart

I am working on this product page. Basically it shows a product by ID and gives you the option to add it to your cart. My problem is that the data stored in $_SESSION gets lost every time I refresh the page.

```
<?php 
    include 'scripts\init.php'; // contains session_start(); and the functions
    if(!IsProductIdSafeAndExisting()) 
    {
        session_write_close();
        header("Location: shop.php");
        die();
    }
    if(isset($_POST['quantity'])) // adds current item to cart but gets lost after refresh
        AddItemToCart($_GET["id"],$_POST['quantity']);

    $id             = $_GET["id"];
    $name           = GetProductField($id,"name");
    $image          = GetProductField($id,"image");
    $price          = GetProductField($id,"price");
    $stock          = GetProductField($id,"stock");
    $details        = GetProductField($id,"details");
    $total_products = GetTotalProducts();
    $total_price    = GetTotalProductsPrice();

    LoadHeaderByTitle($name." | Magazin Vinuri");
 ?>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <?php LoadNavigationBy(""); ?>
        <div id="body">
            <div class="header">
                <div>
                    <h1><?php echo $name; ?></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="singlepost">
                <div class="featured">
                    <img src="images/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="">
                    <h1><?php echo $name.' - '.$price.' lei'; ?></h1>
                    <span>Mai sunt <?php echo '<strong>'.$stock.'</strong>'; ?> bucati ramase.</span>
                    <p><?php echo $details; ?></p>
                    <div class="additem">
                    <center>
                        <form method="POST" action="product.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
                            <input type="text" name="quantity" value="Cantitate" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Cantitate':this.value;" onfocus="this.select()" onclick="this.value='';">
                            <input type="submit" value="Adauga" id="submit">
                        </form>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sidebar">
                    <h1>Cosul tau</h1>
                    <img src="images/cart.png" alt="">
                    <h2><?php echo $total_price; ?> lei</h2><br>
                    <p>Momentan aveti <strong><?php echo $total_products; ?></strong> produse in cos. Pentru a edita lista de produse dati click pe butonul de mai jos.</p>
                    <a href="cart.php" class="more">vezi cumparaturi</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php include 'scripts\overall\foot.php' ?>
```

init.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'database\connect.php';
    require 'functions\general.php';

    require 'functions\engine.php';
?>
```

Comment: What is the job of your `AddItemToCart()`, it will be helpfull if you paste code of that function.

Comment: @AsmirZahirovic the problem was in the function. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that I stored product ids like this $_SESSION[10]=something; which was wrong because it the same as $_SESSION['10']=something; so i changed it to $_SESSION['id_10']=something; and now it works